# Android App Lock AND see the notification

Tags: security, notifications, android-14

When using app lock, the notification from the locked apps show as "1 new message"  (and not the content)

This forces me to open the notification/app to see the content of the notification.
if its a messaging app or email app, it forces me to open/read the message/email

Is there a way to keep the app lock behind finger/face, but still show the content of the notifications?

OnePlus
Android 14
Oxygen OS 14

Comment: Also a related problem.  Some e-commerce app may send you something like "see the latest sales at 50% discount"   but since you don't see the content,  you click on it,  and it sends you directly to the list of items on sales,  and you don't get a chance to read the real content of the push.

Comment: Please don't use comments to add additional info to your question. Simply edit the question. Comments is for discussion with other users. BTW. Your description is not quite clear but I would assume you are talking about lock screen, correct? In Android settings you can chose if notifications are shown fully or without details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change this on my Android, have a look at your phone settings.

- Settings
- Notifications
- Lock Screen Notification
- Select Show Content

[image]

[image]